# C# Raise number to power

Tags: c#, math, integer

I recently stumbled upon a weird bug in one of my programs.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (bitArray[i])
    {
        returnValue = returnValue + 2 ^ (7 - i);
    }
}
```

In the snippet above, if `returnValue = 0`, by the time it reaches a set bit at `i = 7`, the resulting output is 2, which makes no sense (2^0 should be 1). However if I replace the code with:

```
returnValue = returnValue + Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2,(7 - i)));
```

It is evaluated correctly to `returnValue = 1`

The problem is solved by using `Math.Pow()`, but I would very much like to know why it happens in the initial code.

Comment: In C#, the operator ^ is logical XOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, it is probably simplest if you just use the C# left-shift operator `<<`, assuming `bitArray.Length` is less than or equal to 8:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (bitArray[i])
    {
        returnValue = returnValue + 1 << (7 - i);
    }
}
```

If `returnValue` is a float type and the intention is to allow negative powers of 2, then a slight change yields:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (bitArray[i])
    {
        returnValue = returnValue + ((7-i) >= 0) ? 1 << (7 - i) : 1.0 / ((1 << (7 - i));
    }
}
```

although in this case `Math.Pow(2, 7 - i)` is much cleaner.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (bitArray[i])
    {
        returnValue = returnValue + Math.Pow(2, 7 - i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C# (and many other languages) the ^ operator is the boolean logical XOR.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) document for more information about boolean operators in C#.

Answer (score 1):

As @IshaySela and @Adomas have said, ^ is a bollean logical XOR.

But in-order to do what you want to do without using math.pow() you can just make an if condition to check if the power is equal **ZERO** or not.

```
if (bitArray[i]) { 
    if ((7 - i) == 0){
       //returnValue += 1;
    }
else{
       //returnValue += 2 ^ (7 - i);
    }
}
```